# Adding Custom Features to Doro Smartwatch: Is Code Modification Possible?

Tags: sony-smartwatch

I have a Doro 'smart' watch and I'm interested in enhancing its features. I'm curious if it's feasible to modify or interact with the code of the Doro Smartwatch V12. If anyone has insights or information about this, I would greatly appreciate your response